# how to draw route in google map using database value?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a database table like this:

[image]

my original route is:

[image]

but, when i load map using database value, it became like this:

[image]

means it not contain all points and the waypoints are changed.I try to load map as same as i created, but no success.

It is worked fine for one route, means for `A to B`.but it create problem when i try to load multiple routes like `A to B to c`.

so what is the problem?

full code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<body onLoad="goma()">
<div id="mappy" style="width:80%; height:400px; float:left; margin-top:100px"></div>

<script>
var map, ren, ser;
var request;
var data = {};
function goma()
{
map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('mappy'), {'zoom':12, 'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'center': new google.maps.LatLng(23.0171240, 72.5330533) })

    ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer( {'draggable':true} );
    ren.setMap(map);
    ser = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    fetchdata()
}

function fetchdata()
{
    var jax = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    jax.open('POST','process.php');
    jax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    jax.send('command=fetch')
    jax.onreadystatechange = function(){ if(jax.readyState==4) {                
        var jsonobj = JSON.parse(jax.responseText);

        try {
                console.log(jax.responseText);
                var tot_length=JSON.parse(jax.responseText).length;
                var wp = [];
                var startos=eval('(' + jsonobj[0] + ')');
                var lastos=eval('(' + jsonobj[tot_length-1] + ')');
                for(var j=0;j<JSON.parse(jax.responseText).length;j++) 
                {
                 var os = eval('(' + jsonobj[j] + ')');
                    for(var i=0;i<os.waypoints.length;i++)
                    {
                         wp.push({
                             'location': new google.maps.LatLng(os.waypoints[i][0], os.waypoints[i][1]),
                             'stopover':false 
                         }); 
                    }
                }

                 alert(startos.start.lat+","+startos.start.lng+"<br>"+lastos.end.lat+","+lastos.end.lng);
                 request = 
                         {
                              origin:new google.maps.LatLng(startos.start.lat,startos.start.lng),
                              destination:new google.maps.LatLng(lastos.end.lat,lastos.end.lng),
                              waypoints:wp,
                              travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                         };

                 ser.route(request, function(res,sts) {
                    if (sts == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                    {
                      ren.setDirections(res);
                    }   
                 });    

            }
        catch(e){ alert(e); }
    }}
}
</script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get over this?

Comment: Did you try something diferent? Did you check the waypoints order? Try setting `stopover`to `true`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your are passing the waypoints in the wrong order. Make sure:

```
 wp[0] = A, wp[1] = B and wp[2] = C
```